# Python 2.7 under virtualenv: broken `site.py`

Tags: python, module, virtualenv, python-2.7

When I create a fresh virtualenv with Python 2.7 I cannot use `site.getsitepackages()`:

```
$ virtualenv testenv -p python2.7 --no-site-packages
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2.7
New python executable in testenv/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in testenv/bin/python
Installing setuptools............done.
Installing pip...............done.
$ cd testenv/
$ source bin/activate
(testenv)$ python
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:05:24) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import site
>>> site.getsitepackages()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getsitepackages'
```

It seems `site.py` does not have new functions that should be there from Python 2.7.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: Even if I don't use `--no-site-packages` the problem remains:

```
$ virtualenv testenv -p python2.7
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2.7
New python executable in testenv/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in testenv/bin/python
Installing setuptools............done.
Installing pip...............done.
$ cd testenv/
$ source bin/activate
(testenv)$ python
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:05:24) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import site
>>> site.getsitepackages()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getsitepackages'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug fixed in later versions of virtualenv. I searched through the tickets, but I could not find the right one...

Comment: Actually this bug havent yet been fixed :(
[Actual bug (closed as DUP)](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/228), [Parent](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/355)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `--no-site-packages`, which causes the new environment to not inherit existing site-packages.

Comment: Yes but the problem is that the `site` module does not have the `getsitepackages()` function, added in Python 2.7.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the env and then trying without `--no-site-packages`? I had the same problem but then after deleting the env and trying again it worked.

Comment: Yes, the problem still persists, see my EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is not what is causing your problem, but it helped me after 4 hours of debugging (also I'm answering the question 1 year later :).

The `virtualenv/bin/python` file must be executable.

So...

```
chmod +x virtualenv/bin/python
```

worked here.